# How do I interpolate between bins on an FFT in python?

Tags: fft, python, interpolation

I have four frequency peaks, which I have after applying FFT. Now I want to know precise values of these frequency peaks. there are different interpolation methods. How can I use this method of interpolation for four frequency peaks by using python

```
k=index of the max (possibly local) magnitude of an DFT
X[i]=bin "i" of an DFT 
|X[i]|=magnitude of DFT at bin "i“
k'=the interpolated bin location

Quadradic Method
y1=|X[k - 1]|
y2=|X[k]|
y3=|X[k + 1]|
d=(y3 - y1) / (2 * (2 * y2 - y1 - y3))
k'=k + d
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: https://gist.github.com/endolith/255291#file-parabolic-py